# Hide buttons when printing

Tags: html, css

I have a page which contains at the bottom 3 buttons with the following coding:

```js
    function printpage() {
        //Get the print button and put it into a variable
        var printButton = document.getElementById("printpagebutton");
        //Set the print button visibility to 'hidden' 
        printButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        //Print the page content
        window.print()
        printButton.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
```

```css
#options {
 align-content:center;
 align-items:center;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="options">
<input type="submit" value="post news" >
<input id="printpagebutton" type="button" value="print news" onclick="printpage()"/>
<input type="button" value="re-enter the news">
</div>
```

I managed to hide the print button while printing but i couldn't with the others.

I've searched the internet for the solution, and most questions were answered by adding the `display:none;` in css, but i end up with 3 hidden buttons on the screen.
I only want the buttons hidden while printing

Answer might be simple, my knowledge in web developing is acient.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why not use a media print css file?

Comment: Take a look @ print stylesheet: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use CSS `@media` queries. For instance:

```css
@media print {
  #printPageButton {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="printPageButton" onClick="window.print();">Print</button>
```

The styles defined within the `@media print` block will only be applied when printing the page. You can test it by clicking the print button in the snippet; you'll get a blank page.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a css media query to target print:

```
@media print {
  .hide-print {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's best to try and use existing identifiers when possible to avoid unnecessarily bloat.  In this case `#printPageButton`.

Comment: Id's are unique and have a high level of specificity so classes are recommended for styling.

Answer (score 3):

Assign an id to the other 2 buttons. For the POST NEWS button you can set id to `postnews` and RE-ENTER THE NEWS to `reenterthenews`; Then do this

```
function printpage() {

    //Get the print button and put it into a variable
    var printButton = document.getElementById("printpagebutton");
    var postButton = document.getElementById("postnews");
    var reenterButton = document.getElementById("reenterthenews");

    //Set the button visibility to 'hidden' 
    printButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    postButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    reenterButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';

    //Print the page content
    window.print()

    //Restore button visibility
    printButton.style.visibility = 'visible';
    postButton.style.visibility = 'visible';
    reenterButton.style.visibility = 'visible';

}
```

HTML

```
<div id="options">
<input type="submit" id="postnews" value="post news" >
<input id="printpagebutton" type="button" value="print news" onclick="printpage()"/>
<input type="button" id="reenterthenews" value="re-enter the news">
</div>
```