# I want to hide data table excel button on print

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, media-queries

I have `excel` data table button I want to hide in print page.

```
  <style type="text/css" media="screen"> 
       @media print {
             .buttons-excel {
                display: none;
            }
          }
      </style>

<section class="content">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="table-responsive">
           <table id="loading_sheet_table" class="table table-bordered  table-sm" style=" overflow: auto;">
          </table>
       </div>
     </div>
    </section>


<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#loading_sheet_table').DataTable( {
    "paging": false,
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [
          'excel'
      ]
  } );
} );  

   function printContent(e1) {
   event.preventDefault();
        var allVals = [];
      $('input[name=selectedrecord]:not(:checked').each(function() {
         allVals.push($(this).val());
         });
           allVals.forEach(function(i){
          $('tr').each(function(){
          $(this).find('td, th').eq(i-1).css({
                     display:'none'
         });
      });
    });

    $('#print').css('visibility', 'hidden'); //hiding print button on print page
    $('input[name=selectedrecord]').css('visibility', 'hidden'); //hiding Check box on print page
    var restorepage     = document.innterHTML;
    var printContent    = document.getElementById(e1).innterHTML;
    document.innterHTML = printContent;
    window.print();
    document.location.href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"; 
    location.href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>booking/report/loading_sheet/LoadingSheetController/loadingSheetPage", 'refresh';
     }
</script>
```

I using @media Print for hide button but it not working.

Comment: If your question is about buttons with class `buttons-excel`, you should show us those buttons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide buttons when printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31425557/hide-buttons-when-printing)

Comment: @MrLister `buttons: [
          'excel'
      ] `  this excel button  I want to hide in print page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove or modify the media attribute

`<style type="text/css" media="print">`

Comment: Yes, and with `media="print"`, you won't need the @media query.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.
I think you just need to use Datatable print option

```
<section class="content">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="table-responsive">
       <table id="loading_sheet_table" class="table table-bordered  table-sm" style=" overflow: auto;">
      </table>
   </div>
 </div>
</section>


<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#loading_sheet_table').DataTable( {
    "paging": false,
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [
          'excel',
          'print'
      ]
  } );
} );
```

Hope it will solve your issue.